# How to include a special character in a text variable (in JS / app scripts)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am using a Google app script to automatically populate a team vacation calendar. It automatically adds events to the vacation calendar based on keywords. Here is how the keywords are defined:

```js
let KEYWORDS = ['vacation', 'ooo', 'out of office', 'offline', 'holiday', 'holidays', 'out', 'C-Day'];
```

It works fine except for C-Day. (When someone creates an event named "C-Day" in their calendar it is not recognized by the script.)

I have tried 'C-Day', 'C\-Day', 'C-Day', 'C&#45;Day', 'C&#\8\2\1\1;Day' and some variations on those without success.

This feels like a novice mistake on my part, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

FYI - I am using these instructions... https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview and copied/modified this AppScript project... https://script.google.com/home/projects/1jvPSSwJcuLzlDLDy2dr-qorjihiTNAW2H6B5k-dJxHjEPX6hMcNghzSh/edit

Comment: There is nothing special about a string "C-Day".  All you changed was add or change the list of keywords in KEYWORDS?  You are running this from a bound script or a library?  If library you may need to redeploy.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 

That was not the answer, but you did help me find the solution! To check it was a deployment issue I tested new keywords like "test52" and "test-53". Then I say that these were both recognised. So the edited version and now one with a hyphen worked!! WTF?

Further testing showed that keywords must all be in lower-case. So 'c-day' in the script correctly registered "C-Day" in the calendar. Meaning problem fixed! (Added a comment to remind my future self.)  

Thank you for taking time to respond. It did help in the end.

Comment: Update - I was too quick to think it was solved. It works with my calendar, and it works with some other calendars. But it does not work with some of the calendars that are in the Google group. I think I will need to do some testing when people are back after Easter. 

FYI - The script is hosted by Google like this one:  https://script.google.com/home/projects/1jvPSSwJcuLzlDLDy2dr-qorjihiTNAW2H6B5k-dJxHjEPX6hMcNghzSh/edit

It is set to "sync" and I click "run" to test it. It functions for sure, and I see the effect if I make changes.